# "This is considered..." vs. "This is considered as..."

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

Does this "as" change the meaning or correctness of this sentence?

> This is considered **as** socially desired.
>   This is considered socially desired.

Are both of them grammatically correct? Why or why not?